# Can't change font style?

Tags: gimp

Gimp shows no button to select a different font in the text editing tool:
[image]

Everything I saw in tutorials has a little button you click to choose the font style, but I do not see one.

Comment: after all, Font Preview and Font Chooser [are implemented as a ... very badly](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/117654/149982). It isn't intuitive, it isn't convenient, it isn't usable. I respect all the efforts of the developer team, but the fact is the fact

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That looks like the pop-up quick toolbar that appears over the selected area. There should be a "Tool Options" tab in one of the floating toolboxes (mine is on the bottom-left side of the screen by default) that has additional options when the Text tool is selected. If it's not there you can add it to a toolbox through the little left-pointing triangle on the tab bar.

[image: Toolbar]

Comment: That will only change the font of parts of the text that have never been changed via the on-canvas dialog, though.

Comment: i had to double click the text 'A' button to get the 'Tool Options"

Answer (score 4):

In this on-canvas dialog, you choose a font by typing the first (few) letters of its name (in the entry that displays 'Sans' in the screenshot). Then, a selection of matching fonts pops up.

Comment: What happens if you don't know the name of the font you want?  That seems maddeningly unhelpful of Gimp  ;-)

Comment: Then eventually someone comes along who finds this so unhelpful that they add the required code to change it - i.e. someone contributes a new feature.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the square box (that looks nothing like a button but actually is) next to the Font field. That will bring up all of the fonts you have stored on your computer.

[image: illustration]

Comment: Your image doesn't look much like the one in the question — are you sure you're running the same software?

Comment: On March 7, 2023 this was the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The pop-up text editing tool doesn't have the right functionality, so you would appear to need the default docked window for the above solutions to work.

Here's the method to restore it (if it's AWOL):

*Edit > Preferences > Window Management > Reset Saved Window Positions to Default Values* [[src](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=033byQ9c-Nw)]

Then X out of GIMP and reopen, and the other solutions should work at that point.